# How to make a cooldown system with discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Let's say I have two commands...

- `hi 1` that sends hi once to user and starts a cooldown of 500 seconds
- `hi 2` that sends hi twice to user and starts a cooldown of 1000 seconds

Now when I type `hi 1` it should not respond to me when I type `hi 2`.
Something like a shared cooldown system!

How can I do that?

I am currently using this:

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
```

Which allows me to use the multiple commands without stopping for cooldown on a previous command.

Comment: it seems like you might need to make your own check for that, as I don't think dpy has a check for that out of the box

Comment: any idea on how to start that or do that? @Minion3665

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I can work it out. Let me see if I can do it and write an answer for you in a bit

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you could do that, I am trying to check if it is possible to find if someone is already on cooldown!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [custom check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#checks) to ensure that the commands aren't used while they're on cooldown.
`./q63262849/cooldowns.py`

```py
import datetime
from discord.ext import commands

on_cooldown = {}  # A dictionary mapping user IDs to cooldown ends


def cooldown(seconds):
    def predicate(context):
        if (cooldown_end := on_cooldown.get(context.author.id)) is None or cooldown_end < datetime.datetime.now():  # If there's no cooldown or it's over
            if context.valid and context.invoked_with in (*context.command.aliases, context.command.name):  # If the command is being run as itself (not by help, which runs checks and would end up creating more cooldowns if this didn't exist)
                on_cooldown[context.author.id] = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)  # Add the datetime of the cooldown's end to the dictionary
            return True  # And allow the command to run
        else:
            raise commands.CommandOnCooldown(commands.BucketType.user, (cooldown_end - datetime.datetime.now()).seconds)  # Otherwise, raise the cooldown error to say the command is on cooldown

    return commands.check(predicate)
```

This can then be imported

`./main.py`

```
from q63262849 import cooldowns
```

and used as a decorator for commands

`./main.py`

```py
@bot.command()
@cooldowns.cooldown(10)
async def cooldown1(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Ran cooldown 1")


@bot.command()
@cooldowns.cooldown(20)
async def cooldown2(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Ran cooldown 2")
```

It is notable that this approach still has some issues, in particular if another later check fails this check will still put the command on cooldown, however these could be solved by putting this check such that it will run after all the other checks.

Comment: @minion3635 I get an error saying function attribute has no attribute cooldown

Comment: @SDG8 have you got a function called cooldowns? The lines that would seem to refer to is `@cooldowns.cooldown(...)`, and that error suggests that you have a function called the same thing.

Comment: its the exact code you gave me, i just changed the 20 and the await ctx.send values

Comment: everything else is the exact same

Comment: So did you put the `def cooldown` in the same file as the `@bot.command`s?

Comment: no i created a py file in the name q63262849.py and used the same command as you gave me

Comment: ahhh, that was meant to be a directory called q63262849 with a file called cooldowns.py. Sorry for my strange directory structure, I should have explained or changed it when I posted.
If you're going to have it in a file called `q63262849.py`, you can replace `from q63262849 import cooldowns` with `import q63262849 as cooldowns`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219269/discussion-between-minion3665-and-sdg8).

Comment: I think that may have done the job, I'll let you know in a few. Also, if you want, I'm down to pay you for this help!